# How to safely unnest SQL array elements to columns?

Tags: sql, arrays, error-handling, google-bigquery

I would like to find out how to safely unnest arrays to columns in Standard SQL (BigQuery), i.e. turning every item of a list in a column.

Consider:

```
WITH shoppingList AS (
    SELECT 'Bob' AS name, ['bananas', 'olives', 'ham'] AS list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Anna', ['toothpaste', 'shampoo']
)
```

I can then easily query:

```
SELECT name, list[OFFSET(0)] as item1, list[OFFSET(1)] AS item2 
FROM shoppingList
```

However things get a bit more complicate when I wish to query for **item3** and **itemN**.

Since SQL array element access is not a function, I cannot use the `SAFE.` prefix, if I query `SELECT list[OFFSET(2)] as item3 FROM shoppingList`, then SQL with complain. Is there a way to implement a SAFE-equivalent and return NULL when no item is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first point, BigQuery has a "safe" function precisely created for this scenario, [SAFE_OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#safe_offset_and_safe_ordinal). Your "test" query would be

```
WITH shoppingList AS (
    SELECT 'Bob' AS name, ['bananas', 'olives', 'ham'] AS list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Anna', ['toothpaste', 'shampoo']
)

SELECT name, list[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as item1, list[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS item2 , list[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] as item3
FROM shoppingList
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't see it in the Working with Arrays documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#finding_lengths

So this will only work with a known max array length, answering point 1. Good! :)

Comment: @Benjamin . . . This answers the question you asked and should be accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sure. Done. What’s the policy when there two questions bundled in one? Should I actually open a new question?

Comment: @Benjamin . . . In almost all cases, yes.  There are some cases where "multiple questions" are really difference facets of the same question.  For instance, if your question were "How do I create three columns from the array?  How do I give them each specific names?".  But `safe_offset()` is the answer to how to access an array with no errors.  A variable number of columns is quite different.